Can I leave South Africa before my 11-month visitor's visa expires, and re-enter on a 90-day tourist visa?
I'm currently in South Africa on a visitor's visa for research activities, valid for 11 months. My visa expires 31 Dec, but I would like to stay until end of Jan for personal reasons. My plan is to travel to a neighbouring country (Botswana or Zimbabwe) before 31 Dec, then re-enter South Africa in January as a tourist. My passport is visa exempt and allows me to stay in South Africa for 90 days.
Do you think this would be allowed? I know border hopping is strictly regulated, but I am hoping that because I'm leaving and entering on different visa types that this would be okay? I'd appreciate any thoughts on this strategy. I know that I can also apply for a visa extension but I am less keen to do so because of the many administrative tasks and fees involved.

The last few times I looked into this, finding actual clear and up-to-date legislation on the topic was a nearly impossible mission. My impression is that there is nothing that forbids it per se in this case (due to the different visa types), but as usual, they will wonder, how come you need to visit so soon? This probably depends a lot on the reason (remember than even when visa exempt, you usually need to have a reason, and possibly justify it), how long you intend to stay, whether you have firm plans to leave the country, ties to your home country, and so on.

Thanks so much, this was my understanding too and I think I will just chance it. I will have a good reason to be returning so soon and will also have my flight ticket to leave SA for my home country confirmed so they know that I do not plan to stay long. Do you think that this will just come down to my encounter with the border officer and how well I negotiate my case on the spot?
